# Can't see vertex groups

Tags: vertex-groups

I am following this tutorial http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Your_First_Animation/2.Animating_the_Gingerbread_Man

I am at the **Skinning** step and trying to look at vertex groups like the tutorial shows. Clicking "Select" on one of my vertex groups does *nothing*, however. Nothing new shows up on my screen.

Comment: I assume you are in edit mode? A vertex group by default has no vertices assigned to it, but requires you to select the desired vertices and press the `Assign` button under the vertex groups window.